# BigQuery browser tool doesn't reflect table schema

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a table in BigQuery, and we wanted to change the column name. So we queried all columns, and the one that we wanted to change we used an alias to rename it. It appears to have worked, however the table schema in the browser tool still shows the old column name. We refreshed the project, and it still shows the old column name.

We renamed the field from "`has_info`" to "`ct_info`":

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this a bug in the UI?

Comment: Does the schema display correctly if you do a complete browser-level reload of the UI?

Comment: Yup, that does the trick! But should users really have to do that?

Comment: Nope, it's a problem with the UI. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the UI. The problem is that the UI has cached the schema from the old version of the table, and doesn't realize that it has changed. A complete browser-level reload of the table will fix the problem.

I'll file a bug to see if we can improve this.